# nvd3 Mutibar chart customization change X,Y key names

Tags: javascript, json, nvd3.js

Can i change the X and Y keynames in Data so that i can directly use my JSON data to view in chart and make some range between x Axis Dates

```
var data =[
{"key":"Data 0","values":[{ x: "1996-05-22" , y: 1 },{ x: "1997-06-23" , y: 5 }]}


nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

    chart.multibar.stacked(false);
    chart.showControls(true);
    chart.showLegend(true);
    chart.reduceXTicks(false);
    //chart.xAxis     .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(d) });
     chart.xAxis.rotateLabels(-90);


    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    return chart;
});
```

My sample chart : http://jsfiddle.net/gxc27jav/29/

My requirements

1. 1: Change X key to "Date" and Y as Count in DATA and can use that in
   Chart
2. 2: Make the tickvalues range as realtime dates . Currently its just
   showing all available Dates in DATA.  chart.reduceXTicks(true);
   doesnt makes the range uniform.

Comment: Please use latest versions of d3 js and nvd3. Examples can be found at http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/site.html.
Documentation http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#discreteBarChart

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to Both Questions

```
 nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return d.Date // to show Date propery on X axis
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return d.y
                });

            chart.multibar.stacked(false);
            chart.showControls(false);
            chart.showLegend(true);
            chart.reduceXTicks(false);
            chart.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

            chart.margin({
                bottom: 70
            });




            d3.select('#chart svg')
                .datum(data)
                .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

            var xTicks = d3.select('.nv-x.nv-axis > g').selectAll('g');
            xTicks
                .selectAll('text')
                .attr('transform', function (d, i, j) {
                    return 'translate (-10, 35) rotate(-90 0,0)'
                }); //to adjsut the rotated axis Margins

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            return chart;
        }
```